# Alternative for "Except All" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Standard SQL defines `EXCEPT ALL` which operates as follows ([Postgres fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=54310b86bae5d7869b9a53f718573a40))

```
CREATE TABLE T1(X INT);

CREATE TABLE T2(X INT);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1),(1),(2);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1),(2);

SELECT X
FROM T1
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT X
FROM T2
```

This returns

```
+---+
| X |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

as there is an additional `1` row in `T1` vs `T2`.

SQL Server only allows `EXCEPT` and

```
SELECT X
FROM T1
EXCEPT 
SELECT X
FROM T2
```

returns an empty result set. How can I implement `EXCEPT ALL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXCEPT ALL`is not supported by SQL Server. With the tables

```
t1

a | b
--+--
1 | 1
1 | 1
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 2
1 | 3
```

and

```
t2

a | b
--+--
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 4
```

the query

```
select a, b from t1
except all
select a, b from t2
order by a, b;
```

would return

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 1
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
```

because t1 contains two more (1|1) rows, one more (1|2) row and one more (1|3)  row than t2.

To achieve the same in SQL Server, number the rows:

```
select a, b from
(
  select a, b, row_number() over (partition by a, b order by a) as rn from t1
  except
  select a, b, row_number() over (partition by a, b order by a) as rn from t2
) evaluated
order by a, b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a where not exists clause, this will allow you to not get a distinct list.

```
Use AdventureWorks2017;
Go

Create Table #A (a int, b varchar(1))
Insert into #A (a, b)
Select 1, 'A' UNION ALL
Select 1, 'A' UNION ALL
Select 1, 'A' UNION ALL
Select 2, 'B'

Create Table #B (a int, b varchar(1))
Insert into #B (a, b)
Select 2, 'B'


Select a, b 
FROM #A 
EXCEPT
Select a, b
From #B

Select a, b
from #A as a where not exists (Select 1 from #B as b
where a.a = b.a and a.b = b.b)
```

You can see the different result sets between a where not exists clause and an except by running the above code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

[By definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), `EXCEPT` returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren't output by the right input query.

[SQL Fiddle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTableA (ColA int, ColB int)
CREATE TABLE MyTableB (ColA int, ColB int)
INSERT INTO MyTableA (ColA, ColB) VALUES (15,1),(10,1),(2,1),(2,1),(16,1),(2,2),(3,3),(3,3)
INSERT INTO MyTableB (ColA, ColB) VALUES (1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(2,2),(4,5),(1,1),(4,5)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTableA
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM MyTableB
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3f2d2/3/0)**:

```
| ColA | ColB |
|------|------|
|    2 |    1 |
|    3 |    3 |
|   10 |    1 |
|   15 |    1 |
|   16 |    1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
Select *
from MyTableA as a where not exists (Select 1 from MyTableB as b
where a.ColA = b.ColA and a.ColB = b.ColB)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3f2d2/3/1)**:

```
| ColA | ColB |
|------|------|
|   15 |    1 |
|   10 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|   16 |    1 |
|    3 |    3 |
|    3 |    3 |
```