# field subtraction sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-except

If I would like to subtract the fields from each other,

i.e. in A there are 11 fields described as 'Faktura zakupu' and in B there are 5 fields described as 'Faktura zakupu'. I would like to get a return of records in the form of 6 items 'Faktura zakupu' (11-5 = 6)

I tried the EXCEPT operation, but it does not return the desired results

what operation do i need to perform?

[image]

Comment: How do you determine that `(Faktura zakupu, Original)` from first row of table1 should be matched to `(Faktura zakupu, Original)` from first (and not any other) row from table2?

Comment: @SalmanA is no such possibility without any id?

Comment: if you have ids in both tables and say id #1 from table A cancels id#1 from table 2 then that'll work. But I don't think you have ids like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for "Except All" in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61983526/alternative-for-except-all-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add row number to each row in both tables. Then SQL Server can determine that the first `(Faktura zakupu, Original)` in table A is a duplicate of the first `(Faktura zakupu, Original)` in table B and remove it during `EXCEPT` operation:

```sql
SELECT Name, StatusReq, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, StatusReq ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM a

EXCEPT

SELECT Name, StatusReq, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, StatusReq ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM b
```

It'll return 6 rows from table A... numbered 6 through 11.